# How do I isolate the x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I isolate and solve for the the $x$ in  $x^ \frac 23 = 9$  and do the inverse on the other side of the RHS?

$x$ > 0 was part of the original question.

Comment: Raise both sides to the power of $3/2$

Comment: This was also very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$a^{\frac mn}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$$

Comment: +1 for giving a hint instead of just solving the problem

Comment: This has helped me in arriving at the answer. I used this to apply the inverse on the RHS.

Comment: Did you remember to include both the positive and negative solutions when you raised to the $3/2$ power?

Comment: The question stated the x was greater than zero. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^\frac{2}{3} = 9
$$
You can raise both sides to the 3rd power to get
$$
(x^\frac{2}{3})^3 = 9^3\\
x^{3 \cdot\frac{2}{3}} = 9^3\\
x^{2} = 9^3
$$
Now you can take a square root on both sides to get
$$
x = \pm \sqrt{9^3} = \pm \sqrt{ 3^6 } = \pm 3^3.
$$